# Coldfusion spreadsheet width limit

Tags: coldfusion

We are using Coldfusion 9.0.2 on a Windows server 2008 R2. I have a MS Excel Spreadsheetwhich has 192 rows and 40 columns. When I use `<cfspreadsheet>` to read the .xls file, it seems to read all of the rows and columns. Here is the tag I am using

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#outdir#\#infile#" 
    query="theData2" sheetname ="xyz" headerrow="1" />
```

The `xsheet` has columns `A - AU` populated with data. When I dump the `#theData2#` it shows all of the rows and columns. I then do a `<cfloop query="theData2">` and print out one of the fields for each row.

It looks like any column after `AM` gives the error `"Variable col_name is undefined"`. The same thing happens if I change the `<cfloop>` to `<cfouput query="theData2">`. This appears to be a limitation. Has anyone come across this limit also? Any ideas to get around this are greatly appreciated.

Joe

Comment: You probably need a column qualifier, like "". This will separate the columns correctly, if there is a comma present in one of your text values.

Comment: Could you please post the code you're using to "print out one of the fields for each row"?

Comment: I realized that some of the columns in the spreadsheet were hidden which caused me to miscount to number of columns to include in the <cfspreadsheet> tag. In addition to adjusting the number of columns, I ended up converting the query result to an array of structs to loop through all of the records. Thanks for your help ~ Joe

Comment: Glad you figured things out. Since it turned out to be a localized issue, specific to your environ, may as well just delete the thread.

Answer (score -3):

You can get limited records from the spreadsheet by using rows attributes. Like below code

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="sampleSheet.xlsx" 
    query="theData2"  headerrow="1" rows="5-10">
<cfdump var="#theData2#" />
```

Here my sampleSheet having 15 records. The rows=5-10 will return the records from 5 to 10. Like limit & offset in my Sql. We can pass like 3,4. It's will return 3rd & 4th records only from the sheet. Hopefully it's will help you to get limit records.

And you have used headerrow="1". So the your query header should have column name as your first record of an sheet. Then you should loop your query like example,

```
<cfloop query="theData2">
    #queryNname.columnName#<br/>
</cfloop>
```

But if you are not using header=1 then you can get the query value as

```
<cfloop query="theData2">
    #theData2.col_1# #theData2.col_2# #theData2.col_3#  etc.....
</cfloop>
```

I hope it's will resolve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kannan.P, Thanks for the explanation. It was actually the number of columns being read in that was hanging me up, not the number of records. I realized that some of the columns in the spreadsheet were hidden which caused me to miscount to number of columns to include in the <cfspreadsheet> tag. In addition to adjusting the number of columns, I ended up converting the query result to an array of structs to loop through all of the records. Thanks for your help ~ Joe

Comment: Glad it is working, though fwiw... a query object already *is* an array of structures (of a sort) :)